# Kernel Induced Almost Sure Upper Bound

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\kappa(x,E)\in[0,1]$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ and events $E\subseteq\mathbb R$ be a Markov kernel such that $u(x)=\inf\{u\in\mathbb R:\kappa(x,(-\infty,u])=1\}<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
Under what conditions is the map $u:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ measurable?
And where can I find references (that also cover more general cases)?

Background: For any $X\in\mathbb R$, and $Y\in\mathbb R$ given by $\kappa$ (cf. the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel#Semidirect_product) on Wikipedia) we have $Y\le u(X)$ almost surely whenever $u$ is well-defined. In this sense $u$ is the canonical (tight) almost sure upper bound for $\kappa$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $u$ is always measurable. It suffices to check that the set $u^{-1}\big((-\infty,\alpha]\big)$ is measurable for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ because the corresponding intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But
$u(x)\in(-\infty,\alpha]$ is equivalent to $\kappa(x,(\alpha,\infty))=0$. This follows from the right-continuity of cumulative distribution functions. By the definition of a Markov kernel, the function $x\mapsto\kappa(x,(\alpha,\infty))$ must be measurable, and therefore the preimage of $\{0\}$ under this function a measurable set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two remarks.
Your "therefore" is missing an "e" :-) And, I think we don't need cadlag. We have $x\in u^{-1}$ implies $u(x)\le\alpha$, with $\exists u_n\ge\alpha$ with $u_n\rightarrow u(x)\le\alpha$ from above, $\kappa(x,(-\infty,u_n])=1$, we have $\kappa(x,(u_n,\infty))=0$. Say, the countable union has measure $0$, and covers $(\alpha,\infty)$ since $u(x)\le\alpha$. If you agree, and could adjust the answer, I'd be happy to accept! Do you maybe have a reference? Thanks again! Aside, $u$ has to be finite *everywhere* since we define null sets at runtime (or $u$ is not universal).

Comment: Of course, conversely, $\kappa(x,(\alpha,\infty))=0$ implies $\kappa(x,(-\infty,\alpha])=1$, so $u(x)\le\alpha$ and hence $x\in u^{-1}=u^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha])$, meaning that we also don't need anything extra here.

Comment: I see now, potato, potato.